usb 1-14.1: device descriptor read/64, error -71
tengo un servidor en el que tengo instalado un Ubuntu 20.04.1 y deja de funcionar al cabo de un tiempo, pero investigando me he topado en que da este error cuando se queda bugueado:

¿Alguien ha tenido el mismo problema o sabe que puede causar el error?
Gracias de antemano.

Esto es una pregunta de sistemas, no programación. Te recomiendo hacerla en algún sitio donde sepan tratar con este tipo de problemas (serverfault por ejemplo).

Suena a error de firmware.  Revisa tus USB con "lsusb" desde terminal y mira de encontrar de que dispositivo se trata y busca algun firmware alternativo a ver si así lo arreglas.

Al final se ha solventado era un problema con la grafica no tenia nada que ver con los puertos USB ni con el firmware. Gracias.
